# Estimated power draw for different power states?

Tags: sleep, power, acpi, green-computing

What would be a ***raw estimate*** of the power draw of a semi-modern desktop PC, in different ***sleep*** states? Will the suspended state (with powered RAM) draw much more power then the PC in hibernation (especially, hibernation with the NIC listening for wake signal).

The PC specs are: C2D CPU, with P45 based motherboard and 4x1GB memory sticks. OS is Ubuntu 11.10 (it controls the PCI based components and their power states, if I understand it correctly).

Comment: I'm afraid there isn't much to go on with that information. What is the PSU wattage (eg 600W)? What model of C2D is it (newer versions use less wattage, and are more efficient)? What graphics cards (if any) are installed? How many optical drives/HDD's do you have (not so important if we know PSU wattage)?

Comment: I assume CPU and graphics card both turn themselves completely off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a fallow-up - Using kill-a-watt, it appears that my PC in hibernation uses the same amount of power as in sleep mode eg. 9W.